# Events for listview with filter on jquery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filtering

When i use the filter for a listview, jQuery Mobile adds 2 class on my list but i dont want them: .ui-li-static and .ui-body-inherit

I need to remove those class AFTER the filter is complete.

```
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search">
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried different event (change, keyup...) but i dont find THE event

```
$(document).on( "key", "#filterable-input", function() {
    $('li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-li-static');        
        $(this).removeClass('ui-body-inherit');         
    });
});
```

If anyone have a tips...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 
  $( "#thelist" ).on( "filterablefilter", function( event, ui ) {
   $("#thelist li").removeClass('ui-li-static ui-body-inherit');
  });

  $("#thelist li").removeClass('ui-li-static ui-body-inherit');
});
```

In the pagecreate handle the filterable widget's **[filter event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#event-filter)**.

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hcefa77h/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem.

I tried without much conviction because the class appears when i use filter but your solution works very well!